# Requesting ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION is not showing any prompt

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, location

I am using [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#readme) to handle permissions.

As far as I know when `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission is requested below screen screen must be rendered.

[image]

Instead, Below screen is opening

[image]

Which is app permissions screen in settings.

This is how my Androidmanifest.xml looks like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Can Some one help me in opening the first screen when I request for `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`.

Comment: "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" works only in android 1o and above. I was running this in android 9.